# Right way to use AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

To fire some DataBase queries (not getting any value to load into some tag), I am using `AJAX` in the following way :

```
<script>
/* f() Called on any textBox/textArea value changed */
function f()
{

...///
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //simply to call a jsp page
    document.getElementById("myDivWasteHidden").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
//....
xmlhttp.open("GET","myJSP?var1=somePara",true);
}

</script>
```

**myJSP:**

```
<%  

String comnt= request.getParameter("somePara");
//DB connection...
...

 PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( 
"SELECT  QNO from BLOG where QNAME=?" );
     ps.setString( 1, qname );
..query 2..
some more operations...
some insert statements 

%>
```

This way I can get my job done.But :

1) Is this way Ok?

2) `xmlhttp.responseText` is responding so many times .Even The queries are 
fired many times *why*?

3)Now I have to load dynamically created `div`'s on page load.Is this a good way to achieve this?

Comment: where are you calling `f()`?

Comment: so what do you mean by `responding so many times`? you should get one response each time an input is changed in that case. is it more often than that?

Comment: @andrew Its like after preforming the dataBase queries, it calls the page again.But due toe PK violation I am saved .